# Create Remote Notification with Xcode7 and without to be a developer on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, push-notification

Is it possible to create remote notifications without having a developer program, but using xcode7-beta?

I can push my app to my device, but can I test the notifications also?

Does anybody know anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without having a developer program.

To send remote notifications, you'll need an SSL certificate which you can only generate in the Member Center:

> **You Must Obtain Security Credentials for Remote Notifications**
>
> To develop and deploy the provider side of an app for remote notifications, you must get SSL certificates from Member Center. Each certificate is limited to a single app, identified by its bundle ID; it is also limited to one of two environments, one for development and one for production. These environments have their own assigned IP address and require their own certificates. You must also obtain provisioning profiles for each of these environments.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html))

Comment: okay that means I can test my app, but without any additional feature where I need an Provisioning Profile, correct?Just only push app to device

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you can push the app to your device without a Developer Program (it used to be that you could *only* run it in the Simulator). But this has changed [apparently](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/): you can indeed test the app on your own device without a paid account.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
here you can see, you do not need an developer program, 
I tested my app on my own device without a paid account